# Indexing View on Aggregate Field

Tags: sql-server

I am just wondering if there is any way to create index on agregate field?

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (
id INTEGER,
name VARCHAR(10),
family VARCHAR(10),
amount INTEGER)

CREATE VIEW dbo.test2_v WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
SELECT id, SUM(amount) as amount, COUNT_BIG(*) as tmp
FROM dbo.test2 
GROUP BY id

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX vIdx ON test2_v(amount)
```

I have next error message with this code:

> Cannot create the clustered index
>   "vIdx" on view "test.dbo.test2_v"
>   because the index key includes columns
>   that are not in the GROUP BY clause.
>   Consider eliminating columns that are
>   not in the GROUP BY clause from the
>   index key.

Comment: As I see, it is impossible http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902643(SQL.80).aspx. "There are several restrictions on the syntax of the view definition. The view definition must not contain the following: ... SUM ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the restrictions when creating an unique clustered index on a view is.

> If the view definition contains a
>   GROUP BY clause, the key of the unique
>   clustered index can reference only the
>   columns specified in the GROUP BY
>   clause.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

So you firstly need to create a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED` index on your key, then you can create a `NONCLUSTERED` index on your `amount` column.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX vIdx ON test2_v(id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_test2_v_amount ON test2_v(amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your index needs to include ID most likely. Amount won't be unique enough either

As per the error message

> ...the index key includes columns that are not in the GROUP BY clause....